# Parallel derivatives of two curves with a common end point

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, convergence-divergence, riemannian-geometry, weak-convergence

Let $\xi, \nu$ two smooth ($C^{1}$) parametric curves in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ defined on $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ with $k>2$. Let us assume that the two curves intersect in a sequence of points $x_{n}$ such that $x_{n}$ converges to $\xi(b)=\nu(d)$. Under which generic conditions can we say that the vectors $\dot{\xi}(b),\dot{\nu}(d)$ are parallel in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$? An answer for $k=3$ would be quite significant.

Comment: The derivatives of two different curves are continuous at $b$ and $d$.

Comment: I'd be tempted to talk about concavity if the functions were $C^2$, but this strikes me as quite difficult if we only require that they be $C^1$. Good question!

Comment: The whole situation seems far from generic. But it seems the common chords approach a common tangent line ... so I'm voting that the answer is always.

Comment: the word "support" is being used in a strange sense here

Comment: @TedShifrin What if one of the curves is $\xi(t)=(t,0,0), t\in [0,1]$ and $\nu(t) =(t,0,0),t\in [0,1]$ and the rest of $\nu$ is defined on $(1,2]$ to be a loop that comes back to $\nu(1)$ at right angles to the first part of $\nu?$

Comment: Yes, @zhw. seems to have a counterexample. I guess I was assuming the parametrizations were one-to-one.

Comment: @zhw thanks. When $\nu$ goes back to $\nu(1)$ then you are saying that $\dot{\nu}(1)=(\lambda,0,0)$ with some $\lambda$ and $\xi,\nu$ are simply equal in a left neighborhood  of $1$. True!  However i was talking about generic conditions.  There are other contexts in which this can happen. I am talking in general about non self-intersecting curves and especially the intersection set is countable but not a continuous set. Clearly if two curves are equal over a piece whose measure is not $0$ the derivatives of the two curves are equal in $b,d$.

Comment: @TedShifrin It is clear that $\dot{\xi}(b),\dot{\nu}(d)$ can be parallel in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ in my setting for some special cases. Mainly we do not need a counterexample. My question is about  generic conditions under which this  happen.

Comment: If the parametrizations are one-to-one, then my sentence gives the proof. If not, zhw's given you the counterexample. ... Again, "generic" is not a good term here, as the whole set-up is very non-generic.

Comment: @AlecRhea you can increase the smoothness of these curves at $C^{2}$ if you have some ideas. It is a generic condition at the end! :-)

Comment: @TedShifrin Assume one-to-one parametrisation, then what is the sentence giving the proof?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have read your sentence and I agree that it is positive for  $k=2$. But I do not think it is always for $k>3$.

Comment: That the tangent line is the limit of chords holds in any number of dimensions, @FrancescoCiardiello.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62542/discussion-between-francesco-ciardiello-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: @FrancescoCiardiello It would have been good to make your assumptions clear and precise at the beginning. And, I still don't know what you mean by "generic conditions"

Comment: I believe he is looking for the weakest set of additional assumptions we need on these functions to guarantee that $\dot\xi(b)$ and $\dot\nu(d)$ are parallel in any number of non-trivial dimensions.  I believe that Ted is correct that requiring the parametrizations to be one to one would be sufficient -- are there weaker conditions for parametrizations that are not necessarily one to one?

Comment: This gets especially interesting (imo) if we allow $k$ to range over ordinals instead of natural numbers, removing the implicit condition of being in a finite-dimensional setting.

Comment: I'm more of a set-theorist than anything else so please forgive the possible naivete here, but I believe that if the functions are $C^2$ we should be able to construct a $k\times k$ (?) matrix describing the way these parametrizations are 'bending' near $\xi(b)=\nu(d)$.

Comment: @zhw take these two curves $\xi$ $(t,t,t,t)$ and $\nu$ $(t,t,t,t)$ on $[0.9, 1]$ and they do whatever on [0,0.9] and they are simple curves defined on $[0,1]$. Then $\dot{\xi}(1)=\dot{\nu}(1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. They are non self intersecting curves. It is clear that there are simple examples where this happens including your example. I am convinced that the thesis may happen. Then apart from word generic I am talking about hypotheses and not examples.

Comment: @AlecRhea  one to one parametrisation would be fantastic. I think Ted is writing the proof of this. I have some doubts. Let's see. Thanks to everyone anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Ted Shifrin is right, but let's be clear about the hypotheses:

Thm: Assume $\xi,\nu$ are $C^1$ maps of $[a,b],[c,d]$ respectively into $\mathbb R^k,$ with $\xi(b) =\nu(d).$ Also assume both maps are injective, and that $\xi',\nu'$ never vanish. Suppose $x_1,x_2, \cdots$ are distinct points in $\xi ([a,b])\cap \nu([c,d])$ such that $x_n \to \xi(b) =\nu(d).$ Then $\xi'(b)$ is a positive scalar multiple of $\nu'(d).$

Lemma 1: Suppose $\gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb R^k$ is continuous and injective. Then $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism of $[a,b]$ onto $\gamma([a,b]).$

Lemma 2: Suppose $\gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb R^k$ is $C^1$ and injective, with $\gamma'$ never vanishing. Then there exist $0<c<C$  such that

$$c|t-s| \le |\gamma(t) - \gamma(s)| \le C|t-s|$$

for all $s,t \in [a,b].$

The lemmas are pretty standard results, so I'll leave them unproved here.

Proof of the theorem: Because $\xi$ is a homeomorphism (Lemma 1), $s_n= \xi^{-1}(x_n)$ converges to $b.$ Similarly, $t_n= \nu^{-1}(x_n)$ converges to $d.$ We then have

$$\tag 1 \frac{\xi(s_n) - \xi(b)}{s_n-b} = \frac{\nu(t_n) - \nu(d)}{s_n-b} = \frac{t_n-d}{s_n - b}\frac{\nu(t_n) - \nu(d)}{t_n-d}.$$

Let $f_n = (t_n-d)/(s_n - b).$ Then $f_n >0$ for each $n.$ Furthermore, $|s_n-b|, |t_n-d|$ are each comparable to $|\xi(s_n)-\xi(b)| = |\nu(t_n)-\nu(d)|$ by Lemma 2. It follows that the fractions $f_n$ lie in some $[\alpha,\beta]$ with $0<\alpha.$ Passing to a subsequence $f_{n_j},$ we can assume $f_{n_j} \to f\in [\alpha,\beta].$

Now take the limit of $(1)$ through the subsequence $n_j$ to see

$$\xi'(b)= f\cdot \nu'(d),$$

which proves the theorem.